# Concise listing of statistical model assumptions?

Tags: references, assumptions

I'm still a novice when it comes to statistics, but I've noticed that, while many stats textbooks *mention* that the various statistical tests (t-tests, ANOVA, etc.) rest on certain assumptions about the sample distribution and/or the underlying population distribution, few (that I've seen, at least) seem to *compile* these assumptions into an easy-to-find reference, like a summary table. Is there a website, textbook, or other source that concisely and clearly lays out the assumptions of the most common statistical models?

EDIT: Based on the comments I think I need to clarify my question a little better.

Some context I should have included from the start: I'm a PhD student in business/social science without a strong mathematics background. I've taken a couple stats courses, but I don't have the ability to look a string of Greek letters or other symbols and "get" what they're saying. (Believe me, I've tried.) I need something written in verbal language.

What I really need is help evaluating the papers written in my field and in planning my own papers. I need some way to read a paper and tell if their statistical method was chosen properly or improperly. I don't want to accept on blind faith that a given paper ran its statistics properly.

I get that my question invites years of study, and I know there's a risk of adopting an all-or-nothing mindset if just given a list of assumptions. However, I've been led to believe that some assumptions are critical for a statistical treatment to be valid -- e.g., in linear regression that error terms are independent and identically distributed, that they don't interact with the x variables, etc. It would be helpful at least to have some sense of what assumptions are serious if not outright dealbreakers in terms of whether a statistical test can or cannot be applied to a given study.

Any resources that could be provided in this vein would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doubt you will find anything useful. Assumptions of statistical models and methods is a slippery concept! Which assumptions really matters depend not only on the method, but also on the intended use.

Comment: It’s also easy to mix up the formal assumptions of a statisticsl

Comment: Good textbooks and handbooks *do* present these assumptions, so maybe you're not reading the right ones.

Comment: It's worth noting that the importance of many of the 'assumptions' of statistical models and methods is strongly dependent on context. A list of assumptions might be more harmful than helpful because it invites an all-or-none type of understanding.

Comment: @whuber Could you recommend some of the textbooks and handbooks you mentioned? So far the ones I've seen only present assumptions piecemeal throughout the text, and don't include summary tables of key assumptions.

Comment: If you look at books that derive (or get the student to derive) the theoretical properties of some inferential procedure - an estimator, test, CI etc., you see what they/you assumed in the process of that derivation. So, for example, in order to be able to set a significance level, you need the distribution of the test statistic under H0, which you derive under some set of assumptions. You know what those assumptions are in the derivation. So the way to get all these assumptions is to see how the derivations are done -- i.e. to look at books that cover the mathematics.  ... ctd

Comment: ctd... There's no mystery, those assumptions are generally straightforward to identify. What's a little less straightforward is how important they are -- some procedures are highly robust to some of their assumptions and some are acutely sensitive to some of their assumptions. There's little point worrying overmuch about an assumption that your procedure's properties are barely sensitive to. An example of insensitivoty would be significance level in the presence of heteroskedasticity in an ordinary one-way ANOVA *when sample sizes are all equal*.

Comment: I wish to echo @Glen and reinforce those comments by mentioning that earlier in my career I paid great attention to all statistical papers that performed comparative studies of tests and other procedures.  (I spend more time now performing my own computer simulations to achieve the same ends.) Buried in most of those papers, among the many tables and graphics, is a wealth of information about what works when and why, and the reasons why some procedures fail and others succeed under various conditions.  This information is difficult or impossible to summarize in a table in a textbook.